# Is there a way to make Checkstyle ignore javadocs containing @link or @see?

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

I have some methods where I add links to further classes.
For instance:

```
/**
 * Proxy for {@link com.company.Class#someMethod}
 */
public int someMethod(String input) {
   ...
}
```

Currently, when I run checkstyle with that, it complains about missing @param and @return. But I don't want to add those.
Note that this class does not inherit from the one I want to link to.
The same happens with @see

Is there a way to tell checkstyle to look for the @link or @see and ignore javadoc items missing?

Comment: add comments before and after: `//CHECKSTYLE: OFF` and `//CHECKSTYLE: ON`

Comment: I thought about it, but I don't want to include these comments in the code as people might start misusing them. I wanted something more specific that checkstyle would ignore only for that methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do exactly this, but here is what I did:

1. Created a custom annotation @Proxy valid for methods:

   ```
   @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
   public @interface Proxy {
   }
   ```
2. Each method that is a proxy for another one has a @link and a @Proxy annotation:

   ```
   /**
    * Proxy for {@link com.company.Class#someMethod}
    */
   @Proxy
   public int someMethod(String input) {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Added this annotation to checkstyle.xml:

   ```
   <module name="JavadocMethod">
       <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Proxy"/>
       ...
   </module>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As you are ok with extra annotation, please read http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html chapter "SuppressWarningsFilter". Review another ways to suppress violations in checkstyle at that page.

It might be even good idea to propose new feature - "suppress by message" that will not require any updates of code